# How to backfill a column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database for production environment. Recently we added a new column to a table. So in this table, some rows have NULL value for this column. Now we want all the rows to have a non-null value so we have to backfill the data.

What is the common approach to do backfilling? If I want to write a SQL script to do the backfilling, is there a way to abort the whole operation if any error happens?

Thank you!

Comment: How many rows are you talking about? Depending on the number of rows just an update command will be enough.

Comment: Wrap the `UPDATE` in a transaction. If an error happens, issue a rollback. If it succeeds, issue a commit.

Comment: There is about 74000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Just update the table with non-null value.